# How would Police (and the government) respond to a time traveler?

Tags: government, time-travel, police

Say a house is suddenly thrust backward in time (In this specific case, the house ends up in 1985, but the question can be answered more broadly than that) along with everything inside it, and the yard surrounding it is also transported back in time. This house stays exactly where it was before location-wise, but in a time that predates the house, so there is nothing but an empty field surrounding the property on all sides.

Now, say that the police arrives to investigate the strange appearance of a house overnight. They encounter the residents of the house, who are just as bewildered about this turn of events. The police quickly learn that these people insist they’re from the future, and after a few displays of future technology, the police are convinced.

My question is: what do the police do next? Take the time-travelers in for questioning? Call someone with a bigger hat? Would that someone believe it? Is there a specific government agency that would handle the sudden appearance of futuristic tech? Would these time travelers be detained, and if so, for how long?

I’m asking for a novel I’m working on, and I’m hoping to do something a bit less hand-wave-y than “family is taken to unknown facility by mysterious three-letter government agency”, but if that’s necessary, I’m willing to go that avenue. I’ve tried to find answers to this question on the internet, but there seems to be little literature on the subject of time travel and law enforcement, surprisingly enough XD. Answers to any of the aforementioned questions would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I've seen good stories where the time-traveler is locked up as a dangerous loony. And I've seen good stories where everybody accepts the nice weirdo. Whoever owned the property in 1985 just got a free house...but without any permits filed. I've known bureaucrats who could make that end easy for the owner...and I've known bureaucrats who could make it hard. If folks hassle the time-travelers too much, they could go to Los Angeles and hire [The A-Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_A-Team).

Comment: What country are you thinking of? There would be different responses in different places.

Comment: If in Brixton or Broadwater Farm, surely the house'd stand a good chance of being totally ignored or smashed-up and looted. You're goint to need to be specific about *where*.

Comment: Check the Norwegian HBO series *Beforeigners*, which is about police dealing with time travelers, though from the past.

Comment: Sadly, as it stands, it's a bit too opinion based, as the way everyone will react is a potentially conflict-driving factor in your story. I recommend you to take a look at the society at the time you plan your story to take place. For example: in the United States during the peak of the cold War, they'd be taken in by the FBI as supposed Russian spies. Even if they're not actually suspected to be so by the government, they have future tech, and future tech might be what they need to gain an edge on the Soviet Union. Also in this scenario there's no way such an occurrence would be ignored.

Answer (score 8):

> The police quickly learn that these people insist they’re from the future, and after a few displays of future technology, the police are convinced.

My suspension of disbelief has stopped here. Though cops are never depicted as particularly sharp fellows, if they believed the first stranger's story we would have plenty of "powdered sugar" reaching our cities with the excuse it has been sent from granma for the birthday cake of her beloved grandson.

And I can't see any piece of today technology working particularly well in 1985: no wi-fi, no GPS, prehistoric internet. Would really some fancy hardware convince a cop that those guys came from the future?

They would more likely charge the people in the house for abusive building (if there was no house there and now there is one, they build it with no permission, full stop) and maybe illegal immigration, unless they can prove their citizenship. And if the residents are pretty vocal about their coming from the future, a mental asylum is probably the first location where they would be transferred.

Comment: Do you remember what TV's and computer monitors looked like in 1985? If they have power even the "small" flatscreen TV's would look like magic and dwarf almost any screen the police have seen. Without power there are still Smartphones and tablets, which are several times more powerful than the supercomputers at the time and with better graphics and colors than their TV's, plug in a terabite or two storage device and blow their minds with modern movies. Then there's the cars, kitchen appliances, clothing, furniture materials, powered childrens toys, dozens of manuals and service labels...

Comment: I'm with @Demigan here. Especially smartphones, tablets, and HD TV sets with Blu-ray players will seem like something out of *Star Trek* to people from the 1980s. Use your phone to shoot a video and play it back for the cops. Or, if you have a new *Star Wars* movie on Blu-ray, play it and let them marvel at aged versions of Han, Luke, and Leia - and special effects beyond anything seen at the time (*Aliens* is from 1986).

Comment: I disagree on the technology. In 1985 devices like modern smartphones and tablets were inexistent. You'd only need to take a picture of the cop to show them how advanced your device is (have you seen cameras in 1985?), then get your ear buds and let them listen to some music. I do think the people in the house would suddenly "disappear" after everyone heard how they've got some nice, advanced gadgets though.

Answer (score 2):

The police are not that interested. They have a lot more important things to worry about than some pranksters claiming to be from the future. Nobody seems to remember there was a house there before and people say it appeared overnight, well all very strange, but what laws have been broken and who is pressing charges against who on what grounds exactly?

Things might get a little more interesting if the press were to get involved and or if there was a fight over ownership of the land.

Comment: you can't just willy nilly build a house on land that you don't own. even on your land you need building permits.

Comment: Yes Sir, very true. But it's a city council matter please take it up with the planning department...

Answer (score 2):

**Everyone will refer it up the line**

First, contrary to some other answers, the occupants of a modern (2020) house will have no difficulty convincing police that they have very advanced technology.  The police may not believe the time travel story - they may think it's misplaced prototype military technology or aliens - but they will *not* ignore this.

For perspective - in 1985 movies were rented on VHS or Beta tapes (the format war was still ongoing) and the [Commodore 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64) was the best midrange home computer around.  Touch screens and digital cameras are over 10 years in the future.  Merely demonstrating a touch screen interface and the digital camera capability of a mobile phone will be enough to convince the police that you have technology totally unavailable to anyone else on the planet.

No one at low level will want to take responsibility for this, so this will be bumped up the line to the senior police ranks.  Police and intelligence organisations *always* have liaison arrangements in place, so the spooks will be called in and will in turn bring in security cleared scientific advisors to assess the evidence.  (Police are an important part of domestic intelligence work.)

What happens after that will depend on the results of the debrief and scientific assessment and the decisions made from this.  (It's also story-based, so this is where I stop and you start.)  As the ongoing pandemic has shown, different leaders in different countries with fundamentally identical information available will make radically different decisions.  The reaction is even less predicable because while the displaced householders (presumably) *believe* that they have travelled in time, this is unprovable - they could have travelled from a parallel universe or been planted by super-powerful advanced aliens in order to *appear* to have travelled in time.  The government may try to reverse-engineer technology or take advantage of future knowledge, or they may fear a temporal paradox and avoid doing either.

Have fun with the story!

Answer (score 1):

the parents would be institutionalized while the children seized by state and put into foster care.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on just where the building went up. Is there *proof* that the building literally materialized overnight, or could it be squatters who ran up a shack quickly since the last time someone looked?

- **1985? The height of the Cold War ...**
  People with a wild story and no papers? Hmm. A Soviet psy-op? That gear. Top-secret prototypes they have stolen? Or carried with them?
- **1985? *Back to the Future* reloaded ...**
  There just was (or soon will be) a time travel movie. A publicity stunt? Nah. But on the plus side, the cops and other officials will be primed to *think* about time travel as an explanation. The claims won't come completely cold, even for cops who pride themselves into telling fact from fantasy.
- **Where did that house come from?**
  If it went up literally overnight at a busy intersection, that is hard to explain. Otherwise have they build a house without proper planning permits and now try to talk their way out of it? Who owns the real estate, anyway? Unless he or she presses charges, this might not be a *criminal* matter after all.
- **Clearly delusional!**
  A group with a common and strong fantasy. Any children in the setting? Social services needs to take them out of that dangerous cult. By the way, where are their birth records? *Are* you really their parents?

I would guess the government response comes from the mental health services, plus childcare if there are apparent minors involved.